# How do I create a trayicon with Qt/c++ for all UNIX OS?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, system-tray, trayicon

I'm working with Qt/C++ creating my own app, I want it to be cross-platform, so far everything it's been working great with Qt, the only problem its with the tray-icon.

I create a tray-icon and add a menu to it, this works fine in windows but it's not working in Linux. I test my app in two computers and got two different respond.

In my desktop (Ubuntu 14.04) the tray-Icon appears on the right side of the task-bar as expected but it doesn't show me the menu. And in the laptop (also Ubuntu 14.04) the tray-icon appears on the left side of the task-bar but in this case it does shows me the menu and a message when I double click the icon.

I don't know if there's another way to do this but here it's my code.

```
if (QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable())
{
  //trayicon
  trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
  trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/Imagenes/iconosPERFQ-23.png"));
  trayIcon->setToolTip(tr("PerfQ Client"));
  trayIcon->setVisible(true);

  connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),
                 this, SLOT(iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
  //Menu
  logoutAction = new QAction(tr("&Logout"), this);
  trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
  trayIconMenu->addAction(logoutAction);
  // Add the menu to the trayicon
  trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);

  connect (logoutAction,SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(logout()));
}
```

and the slot for the activated signal on the trayicon

```
void Task::iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
  switch (reason)
  {
    case QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick:
      QMessageBox::information(this,"Double Click", "Double click has been press on trayicon");
      break;
    default:
      ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code's not the fault - Ubuntu changed the system notification few years ago from sni (status notifier indicator) to appnotifier which is working via D-Bus and is not backwards compatible with sni.

Though, there is a package in Ubuntu - sni-qt and sni-qt:386 - which helps to show systray icons for applications built with Qt prior to 5.xx version.

Also, if you're building with Qt 5.xx - upgrade Qt to 5.5. It is working with the new appindicator via D-Bus.

Comment: With Qt 5.5 it's the same problem. I haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the whole project?
You could check, also, if the new Qt 5.5 libs were installed correctly.

And another thing - maybe it's really fixed on Ubuntu 15/04 which I'm on - you could try enabling back-ports in 14.04.

Comment: I rebuild the project several times, also I tested the trayIcon alone in I-m still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `QSystemTrayIcon::activated` on Ubuntu. The only thing that happens when you (single) click the icon is that the context menu opens.

This is a fact you have to deal with, a UI choice borrowed from OS X. It dramatically simplifies the interaction with tray icons, because there is no single/double/right click which every application uses differently. Just the menu that does everything.

Regarding your different behavior: could you check those Ubuntu versions again? It looks like the differences came with the transition from Gnome to Unity. The Gnome way of dealing with tray icons differs in many points from what a current Ubuntu 15.04 is doing in Unity.

Comment: So I'll need to use a different

Comment: I don't know what you try to tell me with this comment, sorry.

Comment: So I'll need to use a different method for Unix?? But which signal should I be expecting in Linux then ?? the double click it's not actually my priority, why I really need to do it's to show the menu. I check the versions, both are Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS trusty, the only different its one it's 64 bits and the other 32 bits.

Comment: Sorry I send it before I could finish writing it, and then the page wouldn't let me edit the comment.

Comment: Could you try moving `trayIcon->setVisible(true);` to the end of the function, when the context menu has been set?

Comment: Well, then you need to write a minimal example that reproduces the error and file a bugreport at Qt or Ubuntu if necessary.